# Ajax update panel scroll bar issue

Tags: ajax, updatepanel, scrollbar, asynchronous-pages

I have one update panel inside which I have datalist.

This update panel triggers every 1 second to retrieve the data from db.

I have kept this update panel inside a vertical scroll enabled div tag.

But when I get new data, the scroll bar is not adjusting automatically !!!

I have tried maintainscrollback option but its not working.

Is there any option to maintain the scroll bar to it original position after the updatepanel triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I prefer to avoid JavaScript, which needs to adjust scroll position each and every refresh/update...

I guess you must have designed page like below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional/Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="height: 400px/300px; overflow-y:scroll;"> 
            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
                ....
            </asp:DataList>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Change it to some thing like this should take care of scroll issue

```
<div style="height: 400px/300px; overflow-y:scroll;"> 
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional/Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
                    ....
                </asp:DataList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Comment: in this case the scroll bar doesnt adjust to the new record added @ the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
<script>
  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
  prm.add_beginRequest(function(){
     window.dTop = document.getElementById('divIdHere').scrollTop;
  });

  prm.add_endRequest(function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
         document.getElementById('divIdHere').scrollTop = window.dTop;
      },100);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem for a webpage I was working on wherein after the panel update the scroll bar didnt work. Putting the UpdatePanel tag inside the div tag solved my issue.

So, change the below

```
<UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
         <div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
```

to,

```
<div>
<UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
</div>
```